# Dismissing MediaStyle notifications

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

New Android MediaStyle notifications in Lollipop don't have a dismiss button. Looks like there is already a bug for it on Google Code.

Does anyone know what's a good workaround for this issue until the bug is resolved?

Should we just delay switching to MediaStyle? Or use one of the actions as the dismiss button?

Comment: Here is a link to the bug https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=958

Comment: it's a feature http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html#LOLLIPOP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One mechanism which appears to work quite well is make the notification ongoing while music is playing and make it not ongoing (allowing it to be swipe dismissed) when the music is paused. This seems to be the technique that Google Music [already uses](https://plus.google.com/+AidanFollestad/posts/FiriUevrM13).

Comment: I've been looking through the [Google Play Music source](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_music/blob/master/src/com/android/music/MediaPlaybackService.java) for a while, but using `stopForeground(false)` isn't working at all in my case. I'm not setting any flags on my notification, and it's still not dismiss-able. If you have some time, could you expand your answer to include a brief example?

Comment: I just notice that the source file I've looking at (the one I linked) hasn't actually been updated in 2 years, and therefore is entirely irrelevant. Any pointers still much appreciated. I'm doing `.setOngoing(false)` on the notification builder when the music paused.

Comment: @Michd If you start your service with `startForeground()` you can't dismiss the notification. You should just use the normal `startService()` to start your service and then show your notification. Then you can use `.setOngoing()` as needed.

Comment: Wouldn't it be best practice startForeground() for a music/audio service? IMO, it would be.

Comment: @jasonhudgins - you're absolutely right and I cover that in my [Media Playback the right way talk](https://youtu.be/XQwe30cZffg?list=PL7kiz-Bl7dzgBfEVJ7S9f9FkTF6OR1J_q&t=1951) - note there are some caveats that the `NotificationCompat.MediaStyle` work around for versions prior to Lollipop.

Answer (score 4):

Adding on to @ianhanniballake's answer:

1. For Pre-Lollipop use:

   ```
   notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowCancelButton(true).setCancelButtonIntent(createPlayIntent());
   ```
2. For post-Lollipop:
   To start a media-player notification one must have surely used `startForeground()` to start the Media Service as a `Foreground Service`. The problem now is that this `Service` is not dismissible. EVEN IF we set the `setOngoing(false)`.

The best practice followed is to make the Service dismissible in the paused state. To do that, when your Media Service receives a Pause state callback, call `stopForeground(false)`. This stops the service, but keeps the notification alive. And it can now be dismissed.

Happy coding.

Comment: This is not work..if you stop the foreground from inside the service after using startForeground() to start that service it will crash on Android O and above after couple of seconds..because you said it's a foreground service but didnt make it foreground

Comment: not working for me. When PlaybackState changes to pause I explicitely call stopForeground(false) but i am not able to swipe away the notification

Answer (score 0):

Easy but probably not the most suitable solution is to just add an Action with a 'close' icon. Then simply provide a PendingIntent which will trigger when the icon is clicked: [image: For example]